# Javascript percentage of winning algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a slots machine game HTML5 + Javascript.
I have found the below algoritm on Stackoverflow, but i need another percentage

```
this.d = Math.random();

        if (this.d < 0.3333) {
        this.nextSymbols = [
            ['320', '320', 'jackpot'],
            ['jackpot', '320', '400'],
            ['320', '320', 'jackpot'],
        ];
    } else if (this.d < 0.005) {
        this.nextSymbols = [
            ['320', 'jackpot', '400'],
            ['320', 'jackpot', '400'],
            ['320', 'jackpot', '400'],
        ];
    } else {
        this.nextSymbols = [
            [Symbol.random(), Symbol.random(), Symbol.random()],
            [Symbol.random(), Symbol.random(), Symbol.random()],
            [Symbol.random(), Symbol.random(), Symbol.random()],
        ];
    }
```

I need to have:

```
 1 of 3 spins to be a winning prize 2 

1 of 200 spins wins big prize
```

Any math expert advice would be much appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: How is "I have 10 big prizes" relevant for the probability of a single spin?

Comment: Hint: 1/3 = `0.3333…`, 1/200 = `0.005` (compared to 50% = `0.5`, 20% = `0.2` in the existing code)

Comment: @Bergi thanks. I figured out

Comment: `<` means less than. So `if (this.d < 0.005)` means that the value is less than 0.005. Any value where that is the case is also less than 0.3333. However the if-test for <0.005 is in the `else` clause of the <0.3333, so nobody will ever win the big prize.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize - as @Bergi and @Richardissimo written in comments.
1 / 3 is 0.(3), but you can just write `thid.d < 1/3` interpreter will calculate it for you.
And if you are making `else if` the second case will never fire. You have to change the order of conditions.